# What is causing this Windows 10 reoccurring BSOD on update (MEMORY_MANAGEMENT ntoskrnl.exe+173ce2)?

Tags: bsod, windows-update, windows-10-preview, ntoskrnl.exe

For the last few weeks, I've been getting a `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` BSOD on my Windows 10 machine. I'm 90% sure it has something to with Windows trying to update (I can trigger it on command when I check for updates, and I'm pretty sure that when it randomly happens its because my computer is automatically checking) but I don't know how to fix it. I've used BlueScreen Viewer and it always lists `ntoskrnl.exe+173ce2` as the culprit, but that's been supremely unhelpful in tracking down what the actual issue is.

Here's a link to a zip that houses a number of my most recent crashes dumps: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Md1lnraVJ7b1diQ3JLaHY3Zm8).

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty much at a total loss at this point.

Comment: you should use windbg to determine the cause of these crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a large Memory/CODE Corruption.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000005150a, The subtype of the bugcheck.

00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MiCopyOnWriteEx
03 nt!MiValidFault
04 nt!MmAccessFault
05 nt!KiPageFault
06 aswSnx

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff8037225d6ef-fffff8037225d6f0  2 bytes - nt!MiDecrementAndInsertStandbyPages+5f
    [ 80 fa:00 89 ]
    fffff803722668c1-fffff803722668c2  2 bytes - nt!MiGetPage+91 (+0x91d2)
    [ 80 fa:00 89 ]
    fffff803722eb112 - nt!MiUpdateWorkingSetPrivateSize+e (+0x84851)
    [ f6:c7 ]
    fffff803722eb126 - nt!MiUpdateWorkingSetPrivateSize+22 (+0x14)
    [ f6:c7 ]
    fffff80372375d13 - nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+1a363 (+0x8abed)
    [ f6:c7 ]
7 errors : !nt (fffff8037225d6ef-fffff80372375d13)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

fffff803`72202000 fffff803`72a19000   nt         (pdb symbols)          d:\sym\dl\nt\ntkrnlmp.pdb\3B6F344A2B5B4042A8B609C34252F1431\ntkrnlmp.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Mapped memory image file: d:\sym\dl\nt\ntkrnlmp.exe\57690704817000\ntkrnlmp.exe
    Image path: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Image name: ntkrnlmp.exe
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Tue Jun 21 11:21:08 2016 (57690704)
    CheckSum:         0076DB33
    ImageSize:        00817000
    File version:     10.0.14372.0
    Product version:  10.0.14372.0
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        1.0 App
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntkrnlmp.exe
    OriginalFilename: ntkrnlmp.exe
    ProductVersion:   10.0.14372.0
    FileVersion:      10.0.14372.0 (rs1_release.160620-2342)
    FileDescription:  NT Kernel & System
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

The Windbg extension function chkimg detects 7 errors in the Kernel file in the dump compared to the original kernel exe.

The file can be faulty on your disk or it will be corrupted in RAM. So run a memory test tool (from Windows) or [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/). If this shows errors remove the faulty RAM.

If the memtests show no errors, run `chkdsk /f` to test your HDD for NTFS issues. If this is fine run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` to detect corrupted Windows files and repair them.

If everything is fine, remove the driver aswSnx.sys/Avast AV suite, maybe it doesn't support those preview of Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'd run a memory test a few times as well as `chkdsk /f`but neither had fixed the problem. It ended up being my Avast antivirus that was causing all the issues. Honestly, I'd hit a wall and was close to reformatting my install, so you made my morning.